# Infinitely small numbers

Tags: set-theory, reference-request

When there is a hierarchy $1 < 2 < ... < \aleph_0 < \aleph_1 < ...$ Can we say anything reasonable and useful about the ordering of the reciprocals of these numbers. To begin: $1/1 > 1/2 > 1/3$ makes sense, but I am not sure about the infinite ones. (For example, how should $1/\aleph_0$ compare with $1/\aleph_1$? I think there is something more to it than defining both of these things equal to 0.) Is there any research on this?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_numbers

Comment: $1/x$ is defined when $x$ is a real number.  But $\aleph_0$ is not a real number.  So (unless you provide a definition) there is no meaning to $1/\aleph_0$.


Comment: I removed the "descriptive set theory" tag.

Comment: I'm tempted to reopen this, so I started a meta discussion - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/663/infinitely-small-numbers/

Comment: Dear Willem, after much discussion on meta, we have reached the conclusion that your question is off-topic for MO. That said, I am sure you will get some very interesting answers if you repost the question on our cousin site http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Repeat after me:  Infinity is not a number.